# Snags running Iphone simulator on Xcode 8.2.1

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator

I am having problems running the iPhone simulator on Xcode 8.2.1, on MacOS Sierra 10.12.3. I read that this could be remedied by disabling the SIP on the cmd+R startup screen but this could affect other applications - I have not gone for this option, someone mentioned on here that it's not a safe way to go. Also, I read on a website it's only a temporary fix.

Are there any other possible ways around this to get the simulator running properly?

Thnx

L

Comment: 1) Don't disable SIP.  Where are you reading that disabilig SIP would help you with your issue?

Comment: 2) What is your actual problem?  You just state that you are "having problems" without indicating what those problems actually are...

Comment: Hi Jeremy, No worries, I reinstalled the software and updated my Mac. All is good now. Thanks for the reply.